# Area 51 fulfilled commitment message in rep history is incorrect

Tags: bug, area-51, grammar

Yesterday I fulfilled my commitment for [Moderators](//moderators.stackexchange.com/), and this is the message in [my rep history](//area51.stackexchange.com/users/92433/programfox?tab=reputation) on Area 51 (click to enlarge image):

[image: +50: referred user fulfilled commitment]

It says "referred user fulfilled commitment", but that message means that I would have gotten reputation because a user, who I have referred, fulfulled their commitment, so that's not the case.

And if we take a look at [Undo's rep history](//area51.stackexchange.com/users/83418/undo?tab=reputation), we see this (click to enlarge image):

[image: +25: fulfilled commitment]

He got 25 reputation points because he referred me and I fulfilled my commitment, so the message should be "referred user fulfilled commitment".

Could these messages be updated please?